# batch FOR loop with FFMPEG

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I want to divide a .mp4 file into smaller .mp4 clips using ffmpeg.

This is the code without a loop:

```
ffmpeg -i source-file.mp4 -ss 0 -t 600 first-10-min.mp4
ffmpeg -i source-file.mp4 -ss 600 -t 600 second-10-min.mp4
ffmpeg -i source-file.mp4 -ss 1200 -t 600 third-10-min.mp4
...
```

How do I make it into a loop in Microsoft DOS? So far I have this:

```
for /r $i in (*.mp4) do "C:\Program Files\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\Users\Name\Videos\2014-12-27-0926-45.mp4" -ss 0 -t 600
```

Also someone said to put -codec copy in somewhere but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `FOR` to generate the commands which increment by `600` using this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET SourceFile="source-file.mp4"
SET Increment=600
REM This is how long the file is.
SET Length=1800
REM For keeping track of the number file we are processing.
SET Count=1

FOR /L IN %%I (0,%Increment%,%Length%) DO (
    ffmpeg -i %SourceFile% -ss %%I -t %Increment% !Count!-10-min.mp4
    SET Count=!Count!+1
)

ENDLOCAL
```